How to access and extract element of list if not perfect string match
That is how part of my list looks like (contains more than 100 000 elements):
> dput(db)
list(`tr|Carl|Normasnow_Human` = structure(c("m", "d", "l", "a", 
"v", "g", "p", "g", "a", "a", "g", "p", "s", "n", "v", "p", "a", 
"f", "l", "t", "k", "l", "w", "t", "l", "v", "s", "d", "p", "d", 
"t", "d", "a", "l", "i", "c", "w", "s", "p", "s", "g", "n", "s", 
"f", "h", "v", "f", "d", "q", "g", "q", "f", "a", "k", "e", "v", 
"l", "p", "k", "y", "f", "k", "h", "n", "n", "m", "a", "s", "f", 
"v", "r", "q", "l", "n", "m", "y", "g", "f", "r", "k", "v", "v", 
"h", "i", "e", "q", "g", "g", "l", "v", "k", "p", "e", "r", "d", 
"d", "t", "e", "f", "q", "h", "p", "c", "f", "l", "r", "g", "q", 
"e", "q", "l", "l", "e", "n", "i", "k", "r", "k", "v", "t", "s", 
"v", "s", "t", "l", "k", "s", "e", "d", "i", "k", "i", "r", "q", 
"d", "s", "v", "t", "r", "l", "l", "t", "d", "v", "q", "l", "m", 
"k", "g", "k", "q", "e", "c", "m", "d", "s", "k", "l", "l", "a", 
"m", "k", "h", "e", "n", "e", "a", "l", "w", "r", "e", "v", "a", 
"s", "l", "r", "q", "k", "h", "a", "q", "q", "q", "k", "v", "v", 
"n", "k", "l", "i", "q", "f", "l", "i", "s", "l", "v", "q", "s", 
"n", "r", "i", "l", "g", "v", "k", "r", "k", "i", "p", "l", "m", 
"l", "s", "d", "s", "n", "s", "a", "h", "s", "v", "p", "k", "y", 
"g", "r", "q", "y", "s", "l", "e", "h", "v", "h", "g", "p", "g", 
"p", "y", "s", "a", "p", "s", "p", "a", "y", "s", "s", "s", "s", 
"l", "y", "s", "s", "d", "a", "v", "t", "s", "s", "g", "p", "i", 
"i", "s", "d", "i", "t", "e", "l", "a", "p", "t", "s", "p", "l", 
"a", "s", "p", "g", "r", "s", "i", "d", "e", "r", "p", "l", "s", 
"s", "s", "t", "l", "v", "r", "v", "k", "q", "e", "p", "p", "s", 
"p", "p", "h", "s", "p", "r", "v", "l", "e", "a", "s", "p", "g", 
"r", "p", "s", "s", "m", "d", "t", "p", "l", "s", "p", "t", "a", 
"f", "i", "d", "s", "i", "l", "r", "e", "s", "e", "p", "t", "p", 
"a", "a", "s", "n", "t", "a", "p", "m", "d", "t", "t", "g", "a", 
"q", "a", "p", "a", "l", "p", "t", "p", "s", "t", "p", "e", "k", 
"c", "l", "s", "v", "a", "c", "l", "d", "n", "l", "a", "r", "a", 
"p", "q", "m", "s", "g", "v", "a", "r", "l", "f", "p", "c", "p", 
"s", "s", "f", "l", "h", "g", "r", "v", "q", "p", "g", "n", "e", 
"l", "s", "d", "h", "l", "d", "a", "m", "d", "s", "n", "l", "d", 
"n", "l", "q", "t", "m", "l", "t", "s", "h", "g", "f", "s", "v", 
"d", "t", "s", "a", "l", "l", "d", "i", "q", "e", "l", "l", "s", 
"p", "q", "e", "p", "p", "r", "p", "i", "e", "a", "e", "n", "s", 
"n", "p", "d", "s", "g", "k", "q", "l", "v", "h", "y", "t", "a", 
"q", "p", "l", "f", "l", "l", "d", "p", "d", "a", "v", "d", "t", 
"g", "s", "s", "e", "l", "p", "v", "l", "f", "e", "l", "g", "e", 
"s", "s", "y", "f", "s", "e", "g", "d", "d", "y", "t", "d", "d", 
"p", "t", "i", "s", "l", "l", "t", "g", "t", "e", "p", "h", "k", 
"a", "k", "d", "p", "t", "v", "s"), name = "tr|Carl|Normasnow_Human", Annot = ">tr|Carl|Normasnow_Human Heat factor", class = "SeqFastadna"), 
    `sp|Marcel|Gokanow_Human` = structure(c("m", "d", "g", "p", 
    "t", "r", "g", "h", "g", "l", "r", "k", "k", "r", "r", "s", 
    "r", "s", "q", "r", "d", "r", "e", "r", "r", "s", "r", "p", 
    "t", "p", "a", "p", "p", "m", "f", "d", "k", "y", "p", "t", 
    "k", "v", "d", "p", "f", "y", "r", "h", "s", "l", "f", "h", 
    "s", "y", "p", "p", "a", "v", "s", "g", "i", "p", "p", "m", 
    "i", "p", "p", "t", "g", "p", "f", "g", "s", "l", "q", "g", 
    "a", "f", "q", "p", "k", "t", "s", "n", "p", "i", "d", "v", 
    "a", "a", "r", "p", "g", "t", "v", "p", "h", "t", "l", "l", 
    "q", "k", "d", "p", "r", "l", "t", "d", "p", "f", "r", "p", 
    "m", "l", "r", "k", "p", "g", "k", "w", "c", "a", "m", "h", 
    "v", "h", "i", "a", "w", "q", "i", "y", "h", "h", "q", "q", 
    "k", "v", "k", "k", "q", "m", "q", "s", "d", "p", "h", "k", 
    "l", "d", "f", "g", "l", "k", "p", "e", "f", "l", "s", "r", 
    "p", "p", "g", "p", "s", "l", "f", "g", "a", "i", "h", "h", 
    "p", "h", "d", "l", "a", "r", "p", "s", "t", "l", "f", "d", 
    "r", "e", "p", "h", "d", "y", "s", "h", "h", "h", "h", "h", 
    "h", "h", "h", "p", "l", "a", "v", "d", "p", "r", "r", "e", 
    "h", "e", "r", "g", "g", "h", "l", "d", "e", "r", "e", "r", 
    "l", "h", "v", "l", "r", "e", "d", "y", "e", "h", "p", "r", 
    "l", "h", "p", "v", "h", "p", "a", "s", "l", "d", "g", "h", 
    "l", "p", "h", "p", "s", "l", "l", "t", "p", "g", "l", "p", 
    "s", "m", "h", "y", "p", "r", "i", "s", "p", "t", "a", "g", 
    "h", "q", "n", "g", "l", "l", "n", "k", "t", "p", "p", "t", 
    "a", "a", "l", "s", "a", "p", "p", "p", "l", "i", "s", "t", 
    "l", "g", "g", "r", "p", "g", "s", "p", "r", "r", "t", "t", 
    "p", "l", "s", "a", "e", "i", "r", "e", "r", "p", "p", "s", 
    "h", "t", "l", "k", "d", "i", "e", "a", "r"), name = "sp|Marcel|Gokanow_Human", Annot = ">sp|Marcel|Gokanow_Human Autism", class = "SeqFastadna"), 
    `tr|Hughie|Perkon_Human` = structure(c("x", "r", "p", "y", 
    "f", "d", "s", "k", "l", "n", "k", "n", "i", "y", "s", "d", 
    "i", "p", "p", "q", "v", "p", "v", "r", "p", "i", "s", "y", 
    "t", "p", "s", "i", "p", "s", "d", "s", "r", "n", "n", "l", 
    "d", "r", "n", "s", "f", "e", "g", "s", "a", "i", "p", "e", 
    "h", "p", "e", "f", "s", "t", "f", "n", "p", "e", "s", "m", 
    "h", "g", "h", "r", "k", "a", "v", "a", "v", "c", "s", "v", 
    "a", "p", "n", "l", "p", "p", "p", "p", "p", "s", "n", "s", 
    "p", "s", "d", "s", "d", "s", "i", "q", "k", "p", "s", "w", 
    "d", "f", "d", "y", "d", "a", "k", "v", "v", "d", "l", "d", 
    "p", "c", "l", "s", "k", "k", "p", "l", "e", "e", "k", "p", 
    "s", "q", "p", "y", "s", "a", "r", "e", "s", "l", "s", "e", 
    "v", "q", "s", "l", "s", "s", "f", "q", "s", "e", "s", "c", 
    "d", "d", "n", "a", "p", "i", "w", "i", "r", "a", "f"), name = "tr|Hughie|Perkon_Human", Annot = ">tr|Hughie|Perkon_Human FAT", class = "SeqFastadna"), 
    `tr|Cornel|Maxon_Human` = structure(c("m", "r", "r", "m", 
    "a", "l", "k", "k", "l", "k", "v", "i", "p", "k", "e", "g", 
    "y", "l", "l", "l", "l", "d", "f", "d", "d", "e", "d", "d", 
    "d", "i", "k", "v", "s", "e", "e", "a", "l", "s", "e", "v", 
    "k", "s", "p", "a", "f", "d", "k", "n", "e", "n", "i", "s", 
    "p", "q", "a", "e", "a", "d", "e", "d", "m", "g", "d", "e", 
    "v", "d", "s", "m", "l", "d", "k", "s", "e", "v", "n", "n", 
    "p", "a", "i", "g", "k", "d", "e", "n", "i", "s", "p", "q", 
    "v", "k", "g", "d", "e", "d", "m", "g", "h", "e", "v", "g", 
    "s", "m", "l", "d", "k", "s", "g", "d", "d", "i", "y", "k", 
    "t", "l", "h", "i", "k", "r", "k", "w", "m", "e", "t", "y", 
    "v", "k", "e", "s", "f", "k", "g", "s", "n", "q", "k", "l", 
    "e", "r", "f", "c", "k", "t", "n", "e", "r", "e", "r", "k", 
    "n", "i", "n", "n", "k", "f", "c", "e", "q", "y", "i", "t", 
    "t", "f", "q", "k", "s", "d", "m", "d", "v", "q", "k", "f", 
    "n", "e", "e", "k", "e", "k", "s", "v", "n", "s", "c", "q", 
    "k", "e", "q", "q", "a", "l", "k", "l", "s", "k", "c", "s", 
    "q", "n", "q", "t", "l", "e", "a", "v", "k", "e", "m", "h", 
    "e", "k", "s", "m", "e", "v", "l", "m", "n", "l", "g", "t", 
    "k", "n"), name = "tr|Cornel|Maxon_Human", Annot = ">tr|Cornel|Maxon_Human Predicted SV=1", class = "SeqFastadna"), 
    `tr|Usman|Kortes_Human` = structure(c("m", "g", "r", "h", 
    "l", "t", "l", "l", "l", "l", "l", "l", "l", "f", "l", "q", 
    "q", "f", "g", "d", "s", "d", "g", "s", "q", "r", "w", "f", 
    "t", "s", "p", "s", "y", "d", "g", "r", "v", "y", "e", "s", 
    "a", "a", "v", "g", "s", "v", "v", "l", "q", "v", "t", "a", 
    "l", "d", "k", "d", "k", "g", "r", "n", "a", "e", "v", "l", 
    "y", "s", "i", "e", "s", "g", "n", "i", "g", "n", "s", "f", 
    "t", "i", "d", "p", "i", "l", "g", "s", "i", "k", "t", "a", 
    "r", "e", "l", "d", "r", "s", "h", "q", "v", "d", "y", "d", 
    "l", "m", "v", "k", "a", "t", "d", "k", "g", "d", "p", "p", 
    "m", "s", "e", "m", "t", "s", "v", "r", "i", "a", "v", "t", 
    "v", "a", "d", "n", "a", "s", "p", "k", "f", "t", "s", "k", 
    "e", "y", "s", "a", "e", "i", "s", "e", "a", "i", "r", "i", 
    "g", "s", "f", "v", "g", "m", "v", "s", "a", "h", "s", "q", 
    "s", "s", "v", "m", "y", "e", "i", "r", "d", "g", "n", "m", 
    "g", "d", "a", "f", "n", "i", "n", "p", "h", "s", "g", "s", 
    "i", "i", "t", "q", "r", "a", "l", "d", "f", "e", "t", "l", 
    "p", "m", "y", "s", "l", "t", "v", "q", "g", "t", "n", "m", 
    "a", "g", "l", "s", "t", "n", "t", "t", "v", "v", "v", "h", 
    "v", "r", "d", "e", "n", "d", "n", "p", "p", "v", "f", "t", 
    "q", "a", "e", "y", "s", "g", "f", "i", "s", "e", "s", "a", 
    "s", "v", "n", "s", "v", "v", "l", "t", "d", "r", "n", "v", 
    "p", "l", "v", "i", "r", "a", "t", "d", "a", "d", "r", "e", 
    "s", "n", "a", "l", "l", "v", "y", "q", "i", "v", "e", "p", 
    "s", "v", "h", "n", "y", "f", "a", "i", "d", "p", "t", "t", 
    "g", "a", "i", "r", "t", "v", "l", "s", "l", "d", "y", "e", 
    "e", "t", "h", "a", "f", "h", "f", "t", "v", "q", "v", "h", 
    "d", "m", "g", "t", "p", "r", "l", "f", "a", "e", "y", "a", 
    "a", "n", "v", "t", "v", "h", "v", "i", "d", "i", "n", "d", 
    "c", "p", "p", "v", "f", "s", "k", "s", "l", "y", "e", "v", 
    "s", "l", "l", "l", "p", "t", "y", "r", "g", "v", "n", "v", 
    "i", "t", "v", "n", "a", "t", "d", "a", "d", "s", "k", "a", 
    "f", "s", "q", "v", "m", "y", "s", "i", "t", "e", "g", "n", 
    "i", "g", "e", "k", "f", "s", "m", "d", "h", "k", "t", "g", 
    "t", "i", "a", "i", "q", "n", "t", "t", "q", "l", "r", "s", 
    "r", "y", "e", "l", "t", "v", "r", "a", "s", "d", "g", "r", 
    "f", "t", "s", "m", "a", "s", "v", "k", "i", "n", "v", "k", 
    "e", "s", "r", "e", "s", "p", "l", "k", "f", "t", "q", "d", 
    "a", "y", "s", "a", "v", "v", "k", "e", "n", "s", "t", "e", 
    "a", "r", "t", "l", "a", "v", "i", "t", "a", "i", "g", "n", 
    "p", "l", "n", "e", "p", "l", "f", "y", "r", "i", "l", "n", 
    "p", "d", "r", "r", "f", "k", "i", "s", "h", "t", "s", "g", 
    "v", "l", "s", "t", "t", "g", "i", "p", "f", "d", "r", "e", 
    "q", "q", "e", "t", "f", "d", "v", "v", "v", "e", "v", "t", 
    "k", "e", "h", "e", "p", "s", "a", "v", "a", "h", "v", "v", 
    "v", "k", "v", "t", "v", "e", "d", "q", "n", "d", "n", "a", 
    "p", "v", "f", "v", "n", "l", "p", "y", "y", "a", "v", "v", 
    "k", "v", "d", "a", "e", "v", "g", "h", "v", "i", "r", "y", 
    "v", "t", "a", "i", "d", "r", "d", "s", "g", "r", "t", "r", 
    "v", "q", "a", "t", "d", "a", "d", "t", "g", "l", "n", "r", 
    "k", "i", "s", "y", "s", "l", "v", "e", "s", "a", "d", "g", 
    "q", "f", "s", "i", "n", "e", "r", "s", "g", "i", "i", "q", 
    "l", "e", "k", "h", "l", "d", "r", "e", "l", "q", "a", "v", 
    "y", "t", "l", "t", "l", "k", "a", "v", "d", "q", "g", "l", 
    "p", "r", "r", "l", "t", "a", "t", "g", "t", "v", "v", "v", 
    "s", "v", "l", "d", "i", "n", "d", "n", "p", "p", "v", "f", 
    "e", "y", "r", "e", "y", "g", "a", "s", "v", "s"), name = "tr|Usman|Kortes_Human", Annot = ">tr|Usman|Kortes_Human FAT", class = "SeqFastadna"), 
    `tr|Ussman|Kortesa_Human` = structure(c("m", "s", "q", "w", 
    "f", "e", "l", "q", "q", "l", "d", "s", "k", "f", "l", "e", 
    "q", "v", "h", "q", "l", "y", "d", "d", "s", "f", "p", "m", 
    "e", "i", "r", "q", "y", "l", "a", "q", "w", "l", "e", "k", 
    "q", "d", "w", "e", "h", "a", "a", "y", "d", "v", "s", "f", 
    "a", "t", "i", "r", "f", "h", "d", "l", "l", "s", "q", "l", 
    "d", "d", "q", "y", "s", "r", "f", "s", "l", "e", "n", "n", 
    "f", "l", "l", "q", "h", "n", "i", "r", "k", "s", "k", "r", 
    "n", "l", "q", "d", "n", "f", "q", "e", "d", "p", "v", "q", 
    "m", "s", "m", "i", "i", "y", "n", "c", "l", "k", "e", "e", 
    "r", "k", "i", "l", "e", "n", "a", "q", "r", "f", "n", "q", 
    "a", "q", "e", "g", "n", "i", "q", "n", "t", "v", "m", "l", 
    "d", "k", "q", "k", "e", "l", "d", "s", "k", "v", "k", "l", 
    "l", "g", "p", "n", "a", "g", "p", "d", "g", "l", "i", "p", 
    "w", "t", "r", "f", "c", "k", "e", "n", "i", "n", "d", "k", 
    "n", "f", "s", "f", "w", "p", "w", "i", "d", "t", "i", "l", 
    "e", "l", "i", "k", "k", "h", "l", "l", "c", "l", "w", "n", 
    "d", "g", "c", "i", "m", "g", "f", "i", "s", "k", "e", "r", 
    "e", "r", "a", "l", "l", "k", "d", "q", "q", "p", "g", "t", 
    "f", "l", "l", "r", "f", "s", "e", "s", "s", "r", "e", "g", 
    "a", "i", "t", "f", "t", "w", "v", "e", "r", "s", "q", "n", 
    "g", "g", "e", "p", "d", "f", "h", "a", "v", "e", "p", "y", 
    "t", "k", "k", "e", "l", "s", "a", "v", "t", "f", "p", "d", 
    "i", "i", "r", "n", "y", "k", "v", "m", "a", "a", "e", "n", 
    "i", "p", "e", "n", "p", "l", "k", "y", "l", "y", "p", "n", 
    "i", "d", "k", "d", "h", "a", "f", "g", "k", "y", "y", "s", 
    "r", "p", "k", "e", "a", "p", "e", "p", "m", "e", "l", "d", 
    "d", "p", "k", "r", "t", "g", "y", "i", "k", "t", "e", "l", 
    "i", "s", "v", "s", "e", "v", "h", "p", "s", "r", "l", "q", 
    "t", "t", "d", "n", "l", "l", "p", "m", "s", "p", "e", "e", 
    "f", "d", "e", "m", "s", "r", "i", "v", "g", "p", "e", "f", 
    "d", "s", "m", "m", "s", "t", "v"), name = "tr|Ussman|Kortesa_Human", Annot = ">tr|Ussman|Kortesa_Human Signal", class = "SeqFastadna"))

What is the most interesting for me from this list is a vector of letters for specific accession. In another data I have a list of names and probably using loop I will try to access each of these elements and extract the letter sequence. The problem is that in another vector I have only part of the name which is for example Ussman - so the part between two pipes. Is there an effective way (looping through 100 000+ elements won't be easy) to access the specific element from this list and extract in another vector the sequence of letters which comes with this specific name ?
Expected output:
> dput(vec_sequence_letter <- c("m", "s", "q", "w", 
+                               "f", "e", "l", "q", "q", "l", "d", "s", "k", "f", "l", "e", 
+                               "q", "v", "h", "q", "l", "y", "d", "d", "s", "f", "p", "m", 
+                               "e", "i", "r", "q", "y", "l", "a", "q", "w", "l", "e", "k", 
+                               "q", "d", "w", "e", "h", "a", "a", "y", "d", "v", "s", "f", 
+                               "a", "t", "i", "r", "f", "h", "d", "l", "l", "s", "q", "l", 
+                               "d", "d", "q", "y", "s", "r", "f", "s", "l", "e", "n", "n", 
+                               "f", "l", "l", "q", "h", "n", "i", "r", "k", "s", "k", "r", 
+                               "n", "l", "q", "d", "n", "f", "q", "e", "d", "p", "v", "q", 
+                               "m", "s", "m", "i", "i", "y", "n", "c", "l", "k", "e", "e", 
+                               "r", "k", "i", "l", "e", "n", "a", "q", "r", "f", "n", "q", 
+                               "a", "q", "e", "g", "n", "i", "q", "n", "t", "v", "m", "l", 
+                               "d", "k", "q", "k", "e", "l", "d", "s", "k", "v", "k", "l", 
+                               "l", "g", "p", "n", "a", "g", "p", "d", "g", "l", "i", "p", 
+                               "w", "t", "r", "f", "c", "k", "e", "n", "i", "n", "d", "k", 
+                               "n", "f", "s", "f", "w", "p", "w", "i", "d", "t", "i", "l", 
+                               "e", "l", "i", "k", "k", "h", "l", "l", "c", "l", "w", "n", 
+                               "d", "g", "c", "i", "m", "g", "f", "i", "s", "k", "e", "r", 
+                               "e", "r", "a", "l", "l", "k", "d", "q", "q", "p", "g", "t", 
+                               "f", "l", "l", "r", "f", "s", "e", "s", "s", "r", "e", "g", 
+                               "a", "i", "t", "f", "t", "w", "v", "e", "r", "s", "q", "n", 
+                               "g", "g", "e", "p", "d", "f", "h", "a", "v", "e", "p", "y", 
+                               "t", "k", "k", "e", "l", "s", "a", "v", "t", "f", "p", "d", 
+                               "i", "i", "r", "n", "y", "k", "v", "m", "a", "a", "e", "n", 
+                               "i", "p", "e", "n", "p", "l", "k", "y", "l", "y", "p", "n", 
+                               "i", "d", "k", "d", "h", "a", "f", "g", "k", "y", "y", "s", 
+                               "r", "p", "k", "e", "a", "p", "e", "p", "m", "e", "l", "d", 
+                               "d", "p", "k", "r", "t", "g", "y", "i", "k", "t", "e", "l", 
+                               "i", "s", "v", "s", "e", "v", "h", "p", "s", "r", "l", "q", 
+                               "t", "t", "d", "n", "l", "l", "p", "m", "s", "p", "e", "e", 
+                               "f", "d", "e", "m", "s", "r", "i", "v", "g", "p", "e", "f", 
+                               "d", "s", "m", "m", "s", "t", "v"))
c("m", "s", "q", "w", "f", "e", "l", "q", "q", "l", "d", "s", 
"k", "f", "l", "e", "q", "v", "h", "q", "l", "y", "d", "d", "s", 
"f", "p", "m", "e", "i", "r", "q", "y", "l", "a", "q", "w", "l", 
"e", "k", "q", "d", "w", "e", "h", "a", "a", "y", "d", "v", "s", 
"f", "a", "t", "i", "r", "f", "h", "d", "l", "l", "s", "q", "l", 
"d", "d", "q", "y", "s", "r", "f", "s", "l", "e", "n", "n", "f", 
"l", "l", "q", "h", "n", "i", "r", "k", "s", "k", "r", "n", "l", 
"q", "d", "n", "f", "q", "e", "d", "p", "v", "q", "m", "s", "m", 
"i", "i", "y", "n", "c", "l", "k", "e", "e", "r", "k", "i", "l", 
"e", "n", "a", "q", "r", "f", "n", "q", "a", "q", "e", "g", "n", 
"i", "q", "n", "t", "v", "m", "l", "d", "k", "q", "k", "e", "l", 
"d", "s", "k", "v", "k", "l", "l", "g", "p", "n", "a", "g", "p", 
"d", "g", "l", "i", "p", "w", "t", "r", "f", "c", "k", "e", "n", 
"i", "n", "d", "k", "n", "f", "s", "f", "w", "p", "w", "i", "d", 
"t", "i", "l", "e", "l", "i", "k", "k", "h", "l", "l", "c", "l", 
"w", "n", "d", "g", "c", "i", "m", "g", "f", "i", "s", "k", "e", 
"r", "e", "r", "a", "l", "l", "k", "d", "q", "q", "p", "g", "t", 
"f", "l", "l", "r", "f", "s", "e", "s", "s", "r", "e", "g", "a", 
"i", "t", "f", "t", "w", "v", "e", "r", "s", "q", "n", "g", "g", 
"e", "p", "d", "f", "h", "a", "v", "e", "p", "y", "t", "k", "k", 
"e", "l", "s", "a", "v", "t", "f", "p", "d", "i", "i", "r", "n", 
"y", "k", "v", "m", "a", "a", "e", "n", "i", "p", "e", "n", "p", 
"l", "k", "y", "l", "y", "p", "n", "i", "d", "k", "d", "h", "a", 
"f", "g", "k", "y", "y", "s", "r", "p", "k", "e", "a", "p", "e", 
"p", "m", "e", "l", "d", "d", "p", "k", "r", "t", "g", "y", "i", 
"k", "t", "e", "l", "i", "s", "v", "s", "e", "v", "h", "p", "s", 
"r", "l", "q", "t", "t", "d", "n", "l", "l", "p", "m", "s", "p", 
"e", "e", "f", "d", "e", "m", "s", "r", "i", "v", "g", "p", "e", 
"f", "d", "s", "m", "m", "s", "t", "v")


Is this a fasta protein sequence from TrEMBL?

Yes, it is from Uniprot.

Try nms <- c("Ussman"); lapply(nms, \(x) unlist(db[grepl(x, names(db))], use.names=FALSE))
